# NUnit How to attach screenshot to test attachments in Azure Pipeline

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, pipeline, visual-studio-test-runner

We want to attach screenshots to the Test Attachment in Azure pipeline. Currently, we use

- .NET 4.5.2
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.141
- Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver
- Nunit 3.12.0
- Specflow.Nunit 2.4.0

It is similar with the follwing example but we use NUnit rather than MSTest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/collect-screenshots-and-video?view=azure-devops#collect-screenshots-logs-and-attachments

When run the program in VS2017, the screenshots are accessible from the test report. Also, we can see the screenshots in the azure build output.

Here is the code:

```
string fileName = string.Format("Screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hhmm-ss") + ".jpg");

var artifactDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

ITakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = _driver as ITakesScreenshot;

if (takesScreenshot != null)
{
    var screenshot = takesScreenshot.GetScreenshot();

    string screenshotFilePath = Path.Combine(artifactDirectory, fileName);

    screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotFilePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg);
    TestContext.AddTestAttachment(screenshotFilePath, "screenshot");
    Console.WriteLine($"Screenshot: {new Uri(screenshotFilePath)}");
}
```

Visual Studio Test step in Azure pipeline

[image: Visual Studio Test step]

[image: upload test attachments]

After the build runs, there is no attachment

[image: no attachments]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use private agent to run and see if the results are the same. In addition   ,you can set `system.debug=true` to get more detailed log,in the vstest log,you can see the `attachment location`  which vstest looks for attachments in.

Comment: Only difference in the Azure step between yours and mine is the _Test results folder path. I have _$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults_ which is the default one. Could you try with it?

Answer (score 2):

Coming in a bit late on this one, but who knows, this might be helpful to someone running into similar issues.

I cannot see your entire code, but the reason this might happen *could be* because you're trying to save your attachment in your `OneTimeSetup` or `OneTimeTeardown` methods. Quoting from [the documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestContext.html#addtestattachment-37):

> Within a OneTimeSetUp or OneTimeTearDown method, the context refers to the fixture as a whole

...which basically means that using `TestContext` methods or properties is not allowed within `OneTimeSetup` or `OneTimeTeardown` (even though NUnit/Visual Studio won't complain if you do so! Which adds to the confusion)

So make sure you add the test's attachments from within your `TearDown` or test case. AFAIK, there is no way to save attachments from `TestFixture` context.